# Windows 10 keeps turning displays off 1 minute after I lock the screen

Tags: windows-10, sleep, power-management, display-settings, powersave

Irrespective of any display and screensaver settings (that are available by default on Windows 10) my display always goes into power save mode one minute after I lock the screen.

I frequently lock the machine (Windows-L) when I step away for a minute, and would prefer to raise this timeout so that I'm not waiting for monitors to come back on so often.

So far I have tried disabling/extending every sleep timeout setting I could find, turned off the screensaver, and even found a registry setting to allow adjusting 'System unattended sleep timeout' (by setting the reg key below to 2) from advanced power options, which didn't help.

What am I missing?

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\238C9FA8-0AAD-41ED-83F4-97BE242C8F20\7bc4a2f9-d8fc-4469-b07b-33eb785aaca0]
"Attributes"=dword:00000002
```

Answer (score 14):

There is a hidden option in the Windows 10 Advanced Power Options called 'Console lock display off timeout'. First enable access by setting this Attributes reg key value from 1 to 2:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\7516b95f-f776-4464-8c53-06167f40cc99\8EC4B3A5-6868-48c2-BE75-4F3044BE88A7]
"Attributes"=dword:00000002
```

Then use **Windows+X**, **Power Options**, Advanced Power Settings, Change Plan Settings, Change Advanced Power Settings. From here, under Display, you can adjust the **'Console lock display off timeout'**.

[image]